# Не могу сформировать запрос SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Не могу сформировать запрос `SELECT` SQL. Я сделал так чета не получается.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
    $post_user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM user_messages JOIN users ON (users.`user_id` = user_messages.`message_to_user_id` OR users.`user_id` = user_messages.`message_from_user_id`) AND message_to_user_id=$user_id AND message_from_user_id=$post_user_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $post = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($post) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $user_first_name = $row['user_first_name'];
            $message_content = $row['message_content'];
            echo '<div>'.$user_first_name.'</div>'.$message_content.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу сделать так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> James (`$_SESSION['user_id']`) это я, а Arthur (`$_POST["user_id"]`) это мой друг

Comment: Покажите var_dump переменной $result

Comment: Вы код свой дебажили? Нашли этап, в котором происходит ступор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Как минимум надо предотвратить [SQL инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), в данном случае можно так:

```
$post_user_id = (int) $_POST["user_id"];
$user_id = (int) $_SESSION["user_id"];
```

2) И добавить в `SQL` запрос предикат `WHERE`:

```
$query = "SELECT ut.user_first_name AS user_to, uf.user_first_name AS user_from, um.message_content 
FROM user_messages AS um 
INNER JOIN users AS ut ON ut.`user_id` = um.`message_to_user_id` 
INNER JOIN users AS uf ON uf.`user_id` = um.`message_from_user_id` 
WHERE (um.message_to_user_id = $user_id AND um.message_from_user_id = $post_user_id) OR (um.message_to_user_id = $post_user_id AND um.message_from_user_id = $user_id)";
```

В запросе поменял название колонок, в коде поменяйте

```
$user_first_name = $row['user_from'];
```

3) Не используйте устаревшие функции, используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или хотя бы [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

4) Для дебага можно юзать [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) или как минимум [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Например так

```
$post_user_id = (int) $_POST["user_id"];
$user_id = (int) $_SESSION["user_id"];
$query = "SELECT ...";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($post_user_id);
echo var_dump($user_id);
echo var_dump($result);
die('</pre>');
```

### UPD

Обновил запрос – http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa893/10/0

Comment: @KYRAN попробуйте дебажить

Comment: @KYRAN так у вас в запросе выборка только 1 отправителя и 1 получателя, вам нужно запрос другой, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: так я поменял название колонок, посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо брат от души !!!